# C#. Как записать строку в определённом месте текстового файла?

Tags: c#

Существует текстовый файл со следующим (для примера) содержанием:

a

{

b

c

}

Нужно вставить строку, например, после первой фигурной скобки, или после строки с b. StreamWriter осуществляет запись только в конец файла. Как можно реализовать такое средствами C#?

Comment: вставить или записать поверх? Если просто поверх записать, то смотрите как подвинуть текущую позицию стрима. Если именно вставить, то есть остальный данные подвинуться должны, то вам придется файл в памяфть считать, сделать нужные манипуляции, и  полностью его перезаписать.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы делаете что-то не то, ибо то, что вы показываете, очень сильно похоже на JSON или его аналоги, а если это готовый формат, то и работать с ним надо соответствующе.

Comment: [посмотрите на это](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17716/Insert-Text-into-Existing-Files-in-C-Without-Temp)